# What is Tumblr's "Host" and "Points To"?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, tumblr

I would like to implement custom domains on Tumblr but my hosting provider is asking for "Host" and "Points To" input.

Tumblr only provides:

```
A-record: 66.6.44.4
CNAME: domains.tumblr.com
```

See, image below.

**CNAME**
[image]

**A-record**
[image]

What should I input for those fields?

Answer (score 1):

The "Host" is your domain name.  So if your site is `example.com`, you might want to create:

1. record

   - Type: `A`
   - Host: `example.com`
   - Points to: `66.6.44.4`
2. record

   - Type: `A`
   - Host: `www.example.com`
   - Points to: `66.6.44.4`

OR

1. record

   - Type: `CNAME`
   - Host: `example.com`
   - Points to: `domains.tumblr.com`
2. record

   - Type: `CNAME`
   - Host: `www.example.com`
   - Points to: `domains.tumblr.com`

Here is Tumblr's help document on the process: https://tumblr.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/231256548-Custom-domains